# PhpStorm doesn't recognize return type after nesting calls

Tags: phpstorm

When I'm doing a nesting call of a function on an object the PhpStorm stop recognizing the function after some calls. 
**Any idea how to solve this or why this occurs?**

The function is highlighted and I get this following text message (see the code below to see the exact place where it comes):

> Method addColumn not found in subject class. Referenced method is not found in subject class.

My case:

I use the Table class from here: [github magento2 Table class](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9c14af7a97bcf338662de365d2613c7ca9dbf8c6/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Ddl/Table.php)

and my install function:

```
$installer = $setup;
$installer->startSetup();
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table $table
 */
$table = null;

    /**
     * Create table 'acc'
     */
    $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
        $installer->getTable('acc')
    )->addColumn(
        'id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
        'Entity Id'
    )->addColumn(
        'user',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        32,
        ['identity' => true, 'unique' => true],
        'User'
    )->addColumn(
        'general',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        32,
        [],
        'General'
    )->addColumn(... //more columns (let's say that I add 20 columns) - Until here is no problem
    )->addColumn( //then I get here the text highlighted and text message written above the code. - in my case this is the 25th call to the function
        'individual',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        32,
        [],
        'Individual'
    )->addColumn(
        'created_at',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
        'Created At'
    );
```

What I've tried:

to add `@var \Magento\Framewrok\DB\Ddl\Table $table` to the `$table` variable.

Comment: Can you please illustrate this with some screenshots? I'm trying to understand at what point the issue occurs. AFAIK PhpStorm completely stops analysing the long invocation chains at some moment for performance reasons -- I'm just not sure about the number -- it could be around 30 or so (e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33097#comment=27-2497542)

Comment: exactly that's the problem, then I found more from your link in here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17375. Is there a way to increase this limit? PS: I can brake the chain and it will work, that's what i'm doing right now, but I'm interested in the increasing value - if that is possible from settings or somewhere else. And my limit seems to be 25, not 200 like in the post.

Comment: There is no way to increase is at user end AFAIK. Breaking is acceptable solution as for me -- may also work as visual separation between the related column groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance reasons PhpStorm stops analysing the chained calls [at some point](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33097#comment=27-2497542). Cannot say for sure when though -- but approximately at 25th-30th chain; may depends on the code complexity or something else.

There is no much you can do here -- you cannot increase such limit from user end (some hidden setting) AFAIK.

Breaking the chain at some point is the way to go here -- it seems to work fine. Not sure about you/others .. but it's acceptable solution as for me -- it may also work as visual separation between the related column groups or alike.

Comment: if there is no way to increase the limit this is the right answer